# How to add form validation on group of radio button using jquery form validation plugin

Tags: jquery-form-validator

How to add form validation on group of radio  button using jquery form validation plugin. I have tried to add data-validation="required" but its not working.

PFB HTML code :

```
        <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" name="radioInline" data-validation="required"> 
        <label for="inlineRadio1" data-validation="radio_button"> Inline One </label> 
        <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" name="radioInline" data-validation="required"> 
        <label for="inlineRadio2"> Inline Two </label>
    </div>
```

Script code is :

```
$.validate()
```

I have taken the plugin from this url http://www.formvalidator.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a custom validator called custom radio. and add the attribute  "data-validation="custom_radio" on input type

PFB code for your reference:

```
<div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">

    <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" name="radioInline" data-validation="custom_radio"> 
    <label for="inlineRadio1" data-validation="radio_button"> Inline One </label> 
    <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" name="radioInline" data-validation="custom_radio"> 
    <label for="inlineRadio2"> Inline Two </label>
</div>
```

This is javascript code for custom validator where you return boolean based on value. which should get called before $.validate() function.

```
$.formUtils.addValidator({
                                  name : 'custom_radio',
                                  validatorFunction : function(value, $el, config, language, $form) {

                                      if(value==='option 1'){
                                          return false;
                                      }else{
                                          return true;
                                      }

                                  },
                                  errorMessage : 'You have to atleast check one radio',
                                  errorMessageKey: 'badradiobutton'
                                });
$.validate()
```